# $group using $month not working on stringified date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

I am using mLab which doesn't seem to want to let me use `ISODate("2016-06-16T00:00:00.201Z")` so I end up having to have all my dates in mLab as a string line `"transaction_date": "2016-06-16T00:00:00.201Z"`.

Having a stringified date seems to work fine for my data ranges:

```
$match {
   "transaction_date" : {$gte: "2016-04-01"}, 
   "transaction_date" : {$lt: "2016-08-01"}, 
       }
```

However it doesn't like using the date when I attempt to do a final group to sum my results by month number.

```
$group {
   "revenue_month" : {$month : "transaction_date"},
   "net_revenue" : {$sum: "item_net_total_value"
       }
```

Any ideas why I'm getting 'unknown group operator $month' message? Thanks

Here's the full script below:

```
db.datawarehouse.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
// Stage 1 - Isolate correct document types
{
  $match: {
  "object_class" : "Goods & Services Transaction", 
  "object_type": "Transaction", 
  "object_category" : "Revenue",
  "object_origin_category" : "Bookkeeping"
  }
},

// Stage 2 - Restrict data set by date range
{
  $match: {
  "transaction_date" : {$gte: "2016-04-01"}, 
  "transaction_date" : {$lt: "2016-08-01"}, 
  }
},

// Stage 3 - For duplicate handling, sort by invoice number in descending creation date order
{
  $sort: {
  "transaction_reference":1, 
  "object_creation_date": -1
  }
},

// Stage 4 - For duplicate handing use $first to use latest version of all documents
{
  $group: {
  _id: "$transaction_reference", 
  "party_uuid" : {$first: "$party_uuid"},
  "transaction_date" : {$first: "$transaction_date"},
  "transaction_net_value" : {$first: "$transaction_net_value"},
  "object_category" : {$first: "$object_category"},
  "transaction_status" : {$first: "$transaction_status"},
  "object_origin_category" : {$first: "$object_origin_category"},
  "object_origin" : {$first: "$object_origin"},
  "customer" : {$first: "$party.customer.customer_name"},
  "goods_and_services" : {$first: "$goods_and_services"}
  }
},

// Stage 5 - Widen set from transaction level to line item level
{
  $unwind: "$goods_and_services"
},

// Stage 6 - Make the complete data set required per record
{
  $project: {
  {"_id" : 1,
    "party_uuid" : "$party_uuid",
    "transaction_date" : "$transaction_date",
    "transaction_net_value" : "$transaction_net_value",
    "object_category" : "$object_category",
    "object_origin_category" : "$object_origin_category",
    "object_origin" : "$object_origin",
    "item_quantity" : "$goods_and_services.item_quantity",
    "item_name" : "$goods_and_services.item_name",
    "item_category" : "$goods_and_services.item_category",
    "item_ net_total_sale_value" : "$goods_and_services.item_net_total_value",
  }
},

// Stage 7 - Restrict records by item category
{
  $match: {
  "item_category" : "Sales Revenue"
  }
}
// Stage 8 - Group by transaction_date and SUM item_net_total_value
]

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month) about the `$group` operator:

> ... The argument can be any expression as long as it resolves to a date ...

As you pass the operator a string it clearly does not resolve to a date and therefore does not work.

A workaround for this would be to take the proper substring of the date

```
$group: {
    _id: { $substr : ["$transaction_date", 5, 2 ] },
    "net_revenue" : { $sum: "item_net_total_value" },
}
```

BTW: I am not using mLab but I would be surprised if they don't allow dates. See this answer as intermediate 'solution' but I would suggest either creating a new question with the problem you have with mLab and dates or just ask someone of them to be sure your guessed restriction is true, because in the long term it is best to use the proper datatype.

Comment: this works perfectly thanks. I find most JSON validators don't accept ISODate. I checked with mLab and they said it uses the Extended JSON specification rather than Javascript notation. I checked out https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date but am still none the wiser. Do you know what format the date should be entered as if I was writing a JSON document directly? Thanks

Comment: I'm having a brain fart moment, now that I have added the group, I get the month and summed value. I have tried adding the other values from my previous `$project` but it's not working. I just tried adding them to this group - am I doing this wrong? Thanks

Comment: I guess you may want to add them with $first or $last like so $group { _id .., "net_revenue": ..., "party_uuid" : { $first: "$party_uuid" }, ... - as you have to decide which of the possible many values (as you are grouping now) you want to keep in your final aggregate result

Comment: thanks for that, it is now working but I am pretty sure I've doubled up on how I've done this, I would probably have attempted doing my `$project` at the end but not entirely sure I could have got it going properly.

Comment: the problem I'm having is where there are two different categories of transaction within the same month. If I include `item_category` in the group and have to pick `$first` then I only get one category in the month. For example: Month 5 should have both Sales Revenue figure and a Sales Expense figure - by doing it using this grouping, it sums the transaction value and chooses to categorise it by sales revenue in month 5. If you see what I mean, thanks

Comment: Then you may want to swap $first with $addToSet in order to maintain an array of the different values of that field, i.e. sth. like this ..."item_category": { $addToSet: "$item_category" } or if you want to group on both fields then add an additional field to group on like this  _id: { month: { $substr : ["$transaction_date", 5, 2 ] }, category: "$item_category" }

Comment: perfect, that's working, thanks again for all your help